# Pregunta sobre if dentro de una clase en javascript

Tags: javascript, clase, if

queria hacer que si tiene hijo es true me muestre algo, se hacerlo pero no dentro de una clase y si es false me diga que no tiene hijos, hice este churro pero no va, this._hijos es true deberia entrar al if no al else pero no me va, alguien podria ayudarme? Gracias

```js
class Persona{
  constructor(nombre, apellido, edad, cm, hijos, celiacos){
    this._nombre = nombre;
    this._apellido = apellido;
    this._edad = edad;
    this._cm = cm;
    this._hijos = hijos;
    this._celiacos = celiacos;
  }

   presentacion(hijos){
    if (hijos) {
      return 'Hola mi nombre es ' + this._nombre + ' y tengo ' + this._edad + 'años, ' + 'mido ' + this._cm + ' cm ' + ' y tengo hijos';
    } else {
      return 'Hola mi nombre es ' + this._nombre + ' y tengo ' + this._edad + 'años, ' + 'mido ' + this._cm + ' cm ' + ' y no tengo hijos';
    }

  }

  gritar(volumen = ' a un volumen desconocido'){
    console.log(this._nombre +  ' ha pegado un grito' + volumen)
  }
}

let amigo1 = new Persona('ivan', 'garcia lopez', 33, 185, true, true)
let amigo2 = new Persona('Fran', 'Manrique', 33, 185, false, true)

console.log(amigo1.presentacion());
amigo1.gritar(' a un volumen estratosferico')
amigo2.gritar();
```

Comment: Tu código funciona.

Comment: porque si amigo1 tiene hijos me dice que no tiene, entrando al else?

Comment: El problema es que no tendrías que recibir nada en el método presentación, deberías de utilizar tu propiedad this._hijos, hijos siempre será undefined en tu ejemplo por lo tanto false.

Comment: me dice que no puedo pasarle this al metodo obviamente, no entiendo como dices de hacerlo tu? Pero porque vale undefinded, hago un console.log y me sale true EN EL ELSE, vamos que su valor es true

Comment: Aaah vale si this._hijos en el if es obvio perdona, pero igual sigo sin entender porque hijos vale undefined

Comment: Porqué al no pasarle ningún valor al llamar a tu método presentación todas las variables que no han recibido valor por defecto, tiene el valor undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo tienes en el constructor no hace falta pasar el parámetro, quítalo de la función `presentacion` y entonces la condicional debería ser:

```
if (this._hijos) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Estas asignando un argumento que recibirá `presentacion()` pero no le das ningúno. Solo pasale el argumento y listo

```js
class Persona{
  constructor(nombre, apellido, edad, cm, hijos, celiacos){
    this._nombre = nombre;
    this._apellido = apellido;
    this._edad = edad;
    this._cm = cm;
    this._hijos = hijos;
    this._celiacos = celiacos;
  }

   presentacion(hijos){
    if (hijos) {
      return 'Hola mi nombre es ' + this._nombre + ' y tengo ' + this._edad + 'años, ' + 'mido ' + this._cm + ' cm ' + ' y tengo hijos';
    } else {
      return 'Hola mi nombre es ' + this._nombre + ' y tengo ' + this._edad + 'años, ' + 'mido ' + this._cm + ' cm ' + ' y no tengo hijos';
    }

  }

  gritar(volumen = ' a un volumen desconocido'){
    console.log(this._nombre +  ' ha pegado un grito' + volumen)
  }
}

let amigo1 = new Persona('ivan', 'garcia lopez', 33, 185, true, true)
let amigo2 = new Persona('Fran', 'Manrique', 33, 185, false, true)

console.log(amigo1.presentacion(amigo1._hijos)); // Argumento
amigo1.gritar(' a un volumen estratosferico')
amigo2.gritar();
```